# jQuery DatePicker not showing with MVC3 C#

Tags: c#, jquery, datepicker

[EDIT: Working now. Just changed EditorFor into TextBox]

I am just started with MVC3 in C#. And I have stumbled upon this problem.

I have followed some tutorials on adding datepicker functionality to MVC3 project, but the datepicker is not showing on my web project. Here is what I have:

In my _Layout.chtml file I have included the required jQuery dependencies files :

```
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.core.css")" 
    rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.datepicker.css")" 
    rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css" />
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.theme.css")" 
    rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.ui.core.min.js")" 
    type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.ui.datepicker.min.js")" 
    type="text/javascript"></script>
```

This is what I have in my View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
<fieldset>
    <legend>Student</legend>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FullName)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FullName)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FullName)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DOB)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DOB, new { @class = "date" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DOB)
    </div>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
```

}

and on the same file inside the View, I put the script to hook the datepicker into the editor at the top:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.date').datepicker();
});
```

Many of the tutorials suggested to use the EditorTemplate for this, but I assume it is not necessary. Did I miss something? Appreciate all the helps folks.

Comment: Put it at the bottom and see what happens.

Comment: I don't see a reference to the actual jQuery library.  You have referenced the jQuery UI Core, as well as datepicker, but where is jQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe you can use EditorFor and pass in a class.  Instead, try:

```
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DOB, new { @class = "date" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DOB)
</div>
```

TextBoxFor will accept HTML Attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple working demo, Read [this](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker#option-dateFormat)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

  <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker();
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body style="font-size:62.5%;">

<div id="datepicker"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

**@Html.TextBoxFor()** second argument is **object htmlAttributes**

**@Html.EditorFor()** second argument is **object additionalViewData**

So the **new { @class = "date" }** does not have the desired effect on @Html.TextBoxFor()